# Why is this NULL result matching my if statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my if statement. Pretty straightforward:

```
    <?php if ( is_page( 'Level 1 Promo' ) || is_page( 'Order Thank You' ) ) : ?>
      <p style="margin-top:0;">ClickBank is the retailer of products on this site. CLICKBANK ® is a registered trademark of Click Sales, Inc., a Delaware corporation located at 917 S. Lusk Street, Suite 200, Boise Idaho, 83706, USA and used by permission. ClickBank's role as retailer does not constitute an endorsement, approval or review of these products or any claim, statement or opinion used in promotion of these products.</p>
    <?php else : ?>
      <?php foundationPress_footer_nav(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is what I'm doing to test `is_page()`:

```
<?php global $post;
$pagename = $post->post_name;
echo 'page name: ' . $pagename; ?>
```

So everything works okay. But when `$pagename` is NULL the first if statement passes.

I have no idea why. What's wrong and what's the solution?

Comment: can we see this "is_page" function?

Comment: We need to see that `is_page()` function. It probably has something to do with comparing a null value to a not null value.

Comment: Oh, it's a WordPress function. Should I move the question to WordPress Stackexchange then?

Comment: `&& $pagename !== null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the doc you will see :

> Passing Empty Value Returns TRUE
>   Be very careful if there's a possibility of passing an empty value as a parameter to check for a specific page, since the following lines will return true:
>   is_page( '' )
>   is_page( 0 )
>   is_page( '0' )
>   is_page( null ) 
>   is_page(false )
>   is_page( array() )

Answer (score 0):

Lindus is correct.

Other than that you can add an extra check for `empty($pagename)`.

And you could rewrite your if like this.

```
if (is_page(array( 'Level 1 Promo', 'Order Thank You'))  && !empty($pagename)) {
// Returns true when the Page displayed is either Level 1 Promo or Order Thank You
```